# Why is some of my CSS formating lost when using Ajax to call a URL that also passes variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

The link below works perfectly when I copy and paste it directly in to the browser.

https://my_web_site.com/leads_2020_card.php?State_Code_table=ID&category=gas&longitude=-117.400&latitude=46.500

But when I use the following function to call the same page, I loose by background color in leads_2020_card.php, and the starting container is shifted down about an inch. But everything else works and displays properly in the remaining script. FYI, the script below is in a file called php_loader.php" The loader displays until "leads_2020_card.php" finishes a large database search

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">.</script>



<style>

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
}
.center {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.ring {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: ring 2s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes ring {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    box-shadow: 1px 5px 2px #e65c00;
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    box-shadow: 1px 5px 2px #18b201;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0360deg);
    box-shadow: 1px 5px 2px #0456c8;
  }
}
.ring::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
span {
  color: #737373;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 200px;
  animation: text 3s ease-in-out infinite;
}
@keyframes text {
  50% {
    color: black;
  }
}
</style>




    <script>

    function loadingAjax(div_id)
    {
    $("#"+div_id).html('<div class="center"><div class="ring"></div><br><br><font color="white" face="arial" size="4"><b>Searching<br><?php echo $total_table_rows ?> records<div onload="myTimer();" style="color:white" id="demo"></div> <br>Please Wait ...</b></font></div>');
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "leads_2020_card.php?",
    data: "State_Code_table="+State_Code_table + "&category="+category+"&longitude="+zip_geo_longitude+"&latitude="+zip_geo_latitude,
    success: function(msg){
    $("#"+div_id).html(msg);
    }
    });
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: It may be style overrides, but since this is an ajax call, it's possible to restyle whatever you've loaded.  Have you dug into the inspector tools and checked the elements with the background color?  Are there any similarities with the elements? (ie. both body tags)

Comment: I added my style sheet to the code, I should not have any class over-rides that I am aware of

Comment: Bootstrap is pretty good at overriding styles.  If you comment out the bootstrap css (just to test), do the styles make it through?

Comment: Ok, your hint helped, I made sure both body tags had the same color and that issue is solved, but now I have some sort of margin issue.  I will figure it out.  Thanks

Comment: You're welcome!  If you haven't gotten familiar with dev tools for html and css.  They can make finding these issues much easier.  They'll tell you where the dominant styles are sourcing from.

Comment: I am aware of dev tools f12, but the question is do I remember to look there.  And am not the best, but learning how to decipher.  I will check it out, thanks again